# Проблема с Pyinstaller, как сделать чтобы при запуске открывался терминал?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я столкнулся с проблемой в использовании Pyinstaller. Созданный исполняемый файл работал, но не открывалось окно терминала (а моей программе нужен ввод и вывод). Посмотрел help, но нашёл опции '--console' и '--windowed' только в разделе 'Windows and Mac OS specific options', a я использую Linux. Пробовал всё равно подключать эти опции, но это не помогло.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при запуске моей программы в Linux открывался терминал? 
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: В Linux нет предустановленного эмулятора терминала а-ля cmd.exe, там масса разных эмуляторов, и все разные, от Alacritty до Yakuake.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй воспользоваться этим, там можно выбрать скрывать или оставить cmd (terminal) https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: Жаль, но не работает. Окно терминала всё равно не появляется. Может быть это специфика моего дистрибутива? У меня Fedora 30. @hoefling говорил про эмулятор терминала, может нужно его или что-то ещё установить?